# quarkus/opentelemetry - how to propagate traceid through rest call

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, open-telemetry, quarkus-rest-client

I have one `QuarkusMain` app which calls a Quarkus API through `RestClient`

I annotated my `run()` method with `@WithSpan` and was able to get a spanId and a traceId in my QuarkusMain app:

```
 @Override
 @WithSpan
 public int run(String... args) {
   // my business logic
 }
```

The `run` method calls a REST service in another quarkus application through a `RestClient` interface.
The issue is that I am not able to get the same traceId in my Quarkus API.

I saw here: https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry that the context was automatically propagated. Am I missing something ?

**Edit 1 with additional infos:**

For instance, the log in my Quarkus main tells:

```
{"spanId":"1e0a6b40db4a3e24","traceId":"d9a4bc00ab3b2f576223de16f1026fc7","sampled":"true"}
```

The log in my Quarkus API:

```
{"spanId":"6b490589e3a7650d","parentId":"d7b1d6a2ab520e84","traceId":"079089560b1a4d0af84252a86bfa0e74","sampled":"true"}
```

And finally the `traceparent` header received by my API:

```
00-079089560b1a4d0af84252a86bfa0e74-d7b1d6a2ab520e84-01
```

We can see that the traceparent header matches the log in API level. So my conclusion is something is happening between the log in my main class and the call to the API. It seems that others spanId/traceId are generated before calling my api.

**Edit 2 with resources and config:**

Quarkus version: `2.16.4.Final`

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Config:
`quarkus.opentelemetry.enabled=true`

Comment: You're right the context should be propagated. Can you verify that the HTTP request generated by the RestClient has the traceparent header? This will help determine if the issue is with the client or the server side of the request.

Comment: Sometimes this kind of stuff works if a request scope is activate. Can you try the same code but placing `@ActivateContextRequest` on `run()` just for a test

Comment: @DannyDyla there is indeed a traceparent header with this value: `00-079089560b1a4d0af84252a86bfa0e74-d7b1d6a2ab520e84-01`. The log in the quarkus main tells: `{"spanId":"1e0a6b40db4a3e24","traceId":"d9a4bc00ab3b2f576223de16f1026fc7","sampled":"true"}`. And the log in my API tells: `{"spanId":"6b490589e3a7650d","parentId":"d7b1d6a2ab520e84","traceId":"079089560b1a4d0af84252a86bfa0e74","sampled":"true"}`

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci thanks for the tip but unfortunately, the traceId is not the same even if I add the annotation.

Comment: The span ID logged in the client may not be the span id sent in the request. There is a separate span for the HTTP call itself which would be the child of the span logged in your `run` method. To me, it looks like this is working correctly. Are you exporting span data somewhere?

Comment: What version of Quarkus are you using?
As I understood. You have a quarkus service sending HTTP client calls and a  Quarkus server receiving them, Right? 
Do you have a configured sampler (the logs hint to that)? ... Remember that sampled traces will not be sent by the exporter. Do you see the original span on Jaeger?

Comment: @DannyDyla, I agree about the different spanIds, but as I understand, the traceIds must be the same. This is not the case here.

Comment: Can you please share the dependencies you are using and the config?

Comment: @BrunoBaptista I edit with some config info.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see the trace id changed. You are correct they should be the same. It is weird that the trace id logged in the client is different than the one actually in the header. Do you by chance have any other instrumentation agents (possibly a vendor agent of some kind) installed?

Comment: Also, is there anything between the client and the API such as a load balancer that might be adding or modifying headers?

Comment: Which rest client are you using to perform the call?
Also, on the server side, what is the version and the configs you are using?

Comment: No load balancer, I work in my local machine. The only thing I have in my client app is `prometheus`. I use the standard RestClient of microprofile.

Comment: Did you figure out why this happening? I am noticing the same with 2 Quarkus services where I have WithSpan and application.properties changes but then the trace id is different between services